# Pivot Tables with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following data saved as a pandas dataframe

```
Animal Day age Food  kg  
 1      1   3   17   0.1 
 1      1   3   22   0.7
 1      2   3   17   0.8
 2      2   7   15   0.1
```

With `pivot` I get the following:

```
output = df.pivot(["Animal", "Food"], "Day", "kg") \
           .add_prefix("Day") \
           .reset_index() \
           .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

>>> output
   Animal  Food  Day1  Day2
0       1    17   0.1   0.8
1       1    22   0.7   NaN
2       2    15   NaN   0.1
```

However I would like to have the age column (and other columns) still included.
It could also be possible that for animal x the value age is not always the same, then it doesn't matter which age value is taken.

```
    Animal  Food Age Day1  Day2
0       1    17   3   0.1   0.8
1       1    22   3   0.7   NaN
2       2    15   7   NaN   0.1
```

How do I need to change the code above?

Comment: Use `df.pivot(["Animal", "Food","age"], "Day", "kg")`

Comment: Can you add multiple columns to list like above?

Comment: another way `df.set_index(['Animal','Food','age','Day']).stack().unstack('Day').add_prefix('Day')` :)

Comment: I think OP's example might be ambiguous and what is really wanted it to combine pivot and aggregation (so grouping on 'age' wouldn't work)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, what you want is to pivot the weight, but to aggregate the age.

To my knowledge, you need to do both operations separately. One with `pivot`, the other with `groupby` (here I used `first` for the example, but this could be anything), and `join`:

```
(df.pivot(index=["Animal", "Food"],
          columns="Day",
          values="kg",
         )
   .add_prefix('Day')
   .join(df.groupby(['Animal', 'Food'])['age'].first())
   .reset_index()
 )
```

I am adding a non ambiguous example (here the age of Animal 1 changes on Day2).

Input:

```
   Animal  Day  age  Food   kg
0       1    1    3    17  0.1
1       1    1    3    22  0.7
2       1    2    4    17  0.8
3       2    2    7    15  0.1
```

output:

```
   Animal  Food  Day1  Day2  age
0       1    17   0.1   0.8    3
1       1    22   0.7   NaN    3
2       2    15   NaN   0.1    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot`, add other columns to index:

```
>>> df.pivot(df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['Day', 'kg'])], 'Day', 'kg') \
      .add_prefix('Day').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

   Animal  age  Food  Day1  Day2
0       1    3    17   0.1   0.8
1       1    3    22   0.7   NaN
2       2    7    15   NaN   0.1
```